# How to convert List<int> to string[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I need an easy way to convert a `List<int>` to a `string` array.

I have:

```
var the_list = new List<int>();
the_list.Add(1);
the_list.Add(2);
the_list.Add(3);

string[] the_array = new string[the_list.Count];
for(var i = 0 ; i < the_array.Count; ++i)
    the_array[i] = the_list[i].ToString();
```

...which looks to be very ugly to me.

Is there an easier way?

---

**Note:** I'm looking for an *easier* way - not necessarily a faster way.

Comment: That is the most efficient way, unless you were to have many repeated elements in the array. That doesn't mean it's necessarily the easiest way of course.

Comment: It seems like you are asking two different questions: What is more efficient and which is easier.  IMO, the answers to these two questions are different :)

Comment: @Brian: I'm asking which is easier - sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
string[] the_array = the_list.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Note: Although I would certainly choose the Select.ToArray approach laid out here, it is not likely to be faster than what you have already.  Your way is straight-forward and probably the most efficient way.  Again.  I choose the easier-to-read/maintain approach of Select.ToArray (LINQ) that @Etienne de Martel suggests, but your question suggested your option was inefficient.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to pass an unbound method to `Select` and have it automatically bind that to the element, similar to Ruby's `Symbol#to_proc` trick? I.e. something like `the_list.Select(int.ToString)`? (For the Haskell people: I'm basically asking whether there is a pointfree solution.)

Comment: @Ben Voigt could you please explain why this code isn't fast?

Comment: @jb: Because it most likely has to accumulate all the strings into a collection with dynamic size, and then once the final size is known, allocate the array and copy all the elements.  In this example the count is known before the query begins to execute, but the LINQ library doesn't have any way to know that the selection delegate doesn't change the length of the list.  The JIT compiler does, but it doesn't have the contextual knowledge to see how that is useful.

Comment: @Jorg: Yes, creating an unbound delegate is possible.  But there is no syntactic sugar for it, one has to call the Reflection APIs directly.

Answer (score 6):

I know you have a good answer, but you don't need LINQ or Select. You can do it with a ConvertAll and an anonymous method.  Like this:

```
var list = new List<int>();
....
var array = list.ConvertAll( x => x.ToString() ).ToArray();
```

Similar idea, but I think this is not linq. in case that matters.

Comment: For what it's worth, `ToArray` is a static method on the `Enumerable` class, which makes it LINQ in my opinion. Also, there's a good chance that this will be less efficient than using `Select`: `ConvertAll` will create an intermediate list before you then convert that list to an array; `Select` doesn't need to create that intermediate list.

Comment: @LukeH No, it's NOT LINQ.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I don't have .NET installed on this machine, so totally untested:

```
var theList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

var theArray = theList.Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray();       // Lambda Form
var theArray = (from e in theList select e.ToString()).ToArray(); // Query Form
```

Answer (score 2):

List has a ToArray() method. It will save you typing but probably won't be more efficient.

Comment: It also won't convert the array from `int` to `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Because your list only has a number, you can easily convert them to a string. Just create a loop and convert its members to the string.

```
string[] the_array = new string[the_list.Count];
int i=0;
foreach(var item in the_list)
{
  the_array[i] = item.ToString();
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer. Simply posting code can be confusing.